# Intel Fortran: How to get traceback on floating-point exception in f2py-wrapped code

Tags: signals, stack-trace, intel-fortran, traceback, f2py

I have a trivial test program that implements one function, `INV`, which just computes 1/x.   Passing 0 for the argument x triggers a zero-division error.  When I compile it with ifort (version 2021.3.0), using the flags `/fpe-all:0 /traceback/fp:strict /debug`
and run it, I get a traceback like this:

```
forrtl: error (73): floating divide by zero
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
ifort-tst.exe      00007FF7EB0411F0  F_mp_INV                    9  f.f
ifort-tst.exe      00007FF7EB0410A2  MAIN__                      8  tst.f
```

In my real application, we call Fortran code from a Python process, using `f2py`.  With a bit of tinkering (had to define macros `UPPERCASE_FORTRAN` and `NO_APPEND_FORTRAN`) I was able to compile the same code as a Python module.  When I run it from Python, the zero-division causes the program to quit but does not produce the backtrace.  If I don't set `/fpe-all:0` the module just returns a NaN instead of aborting.  I want the program to abort on floating-point exceptions, but I want to see the same type of backtrace that is produced when I run the code as a stand-alone executable.

I suspect that some needed signal handler is not getting registered - with GNU Fortran it's necessary to call a few library initialization functions to make FPE exception handling work (`_gfortran_set_options`, `_gfortran_set_fpe`) but I was not able to find the equivalent in the Intel Fortran documentation.

I'm working on the Windows 10 platform.  I've been able to get backtraces from an f2py module using gfortran in Linux, but for Windows, the `libbacktrace` supplied with `gcc` seems to be non-usable, which drove me to try Intel Fortran.